# Localization not working in Azure Bot Service Node

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I've been playing around with the botframework and Azure Bot Service for quite some time now and noticed that setting the preferredLocale of the session changes the language of all prompts but not the sent texts.

```
session.preferredLocale('es', (error) => {
       if (typeof error === 'undefined') { 
          session.send('greeting'); 
       }
});
```

Setting the locale in this way changes the built-in prompts to Spanish but does not load the localized greeting message but sends the plain-text message 'greeting' instead.

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector).set('localizerSettings', { botLocalePath: "./locale", defaultLocale: "en" });
```

My bot uses the default localization configuration, as shown in this example, but my locale folder is called locale instead of customLocale.

Any ideas?

Comment: Found a solution for this issue:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/issues/2

In short: 
You have to set the bot locale path manually if you want to use localization in a bot service azure node. The problem was mainly that the default locale path was set as a linux path and not normalized across systems. Using path.join solves that issue as it takes the system the Node.js process is running on into account.

Answer (score 0):

This way works for us

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector,
function(session){
    session.preferredLocale('es', function(err){
        if (!err) {
            console.log("Locale: es");
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
...
```

Works well on webchat and directline(this one happens to be always in EN, but we need it in ES)